# Simple products being treated as configurable?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, products

I'm currently working on a site and getting the following PHP error in my logs

Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php on line 160

Which makes all simple products on the site load like the following page http://boxchilli.co/a3mdirect/portable-stands/portable-furniture/crescent.html

Nothing has been installed on the site before the issue came up and only changes made to the site is additional products being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.

Another person had done some coding work for custom user input on configurable products.